# Codeigniter 2 difference between index and __construct and what to put in __construct

Tags: php, codeigniter, controller, construct

When is **__construct** called and when is **index** called? And are there any other differences?

And what to put in **__construct**? Whats the best practice, should I put **$this->load** calls... ? what else?

```
class Site extends CI_Controller {

      public function __construct() {

          parent::__construct();
          echo 'Hello World2';

     }

     public function index() {

          echo 'Hello World1';

     }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**[__construct()](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html#what-is-a-controller)** is called first, then according to URL is called **[index()](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html#methods)** or other functions.

**public function __construct()** should contain:

1. allocating resources used in entire class ex. $this->load
2. check user authentication (if entire class requires it)

**public function index()** should contain:

1. allocating resources used only in this function
2. calling views or displaying anything

it is bad design if **public function __construct()** contain:

1. Displaying anything
2. Any code required only for one function.

Comment: ^ also construct is not only called before the index() method but also before all the other methods of this controller.

Comment: @ThomasDavidPlat thank you for your comment. English is not my native, how construct correct sentence that it will be that constructor called first before anything else?

Comment: Nevermind :) Neither is it my native language. I would write something like: "The __construct() method will be executed during object instantiation, so speaking before any other method of the class is executed"

Answer (score 0):

**index()** will be executed while you call the index function or by default as you can say index() is an default function...Strightly we can say that **__construct()** is the one which will be the first method while an controller is called through its function works as constructor

Answer (score 0):

`__construct` is the [constucter](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php) of the class, while `index()` is the default method.

Suppose that you are calling `http://yoursite.com/` this is equivalent to `http://yoursite.com/your_default_controller/index`

It means, if there is nothing in the third segment of your URL, index() of that controller is called by default.

You can initialize things at constucter and load view and models.

You can pass data to view at the index()

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that you are calling `http://yoursite.com/` this is equivalent to `http://yoursite.com/your_default_controller/index`

`index()` will be executed while you call the `index` function or by default as you can say `index()` is an default function...Strightly we can say that `__construct()` is the one which will be the first method while an controller is called through its function works as constructor